# How do I remap an MVC action parameter to another parameter name?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have to implement an MVC action that is invoked like this:

```
http://address/Controller/MyAction?resName=name
```

and it's called by a third party that is hardcoded to pass `resName`. So the naive way is to have an action like this:

```
ActionResult MyAction( String resName )
{
```

but I think that having a parameter called `resName` is uncool and I'd prefer to have it name `resourceName`. If I just rename the parameter MVC parameter mapping no longer works and I always have `resourceName` set to `null` when my action is invoked.

I tried `BindAttribute` like this:

```
ActionResult MyAction( [Bind(Include="resName")] String resourceName )
```

but `resourceName` is still `null` every time my action is invoked.

How do I remap my parameter name?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`Prefix` is what you need:

```
ActionResult MyAction( [Bind(Prefix="resName")] String resourceName )
```

However, doing a `http://address/Controller/MyAction?resourceName=name` won't work with that setup.

Answer (score 10):

Another option is to use the [ActionParameterAlias](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ActionParameterAlias/) library. The nice thing about it is that both names for a given parameter will work.

e.g.

```
using ActionParameterAlias;
//...

    [ParameterAlias("resourceName", "resName", Order = 1)]
    ActionResult MyAction( String resourceName )
```

Then calls to the controller like `http://address/Controller/MyAction?resourceName=name` **and** `http://address/Controller/MyAction?resName=name` will both work just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, ActionParameterAlias fails if you use a property of type DateTime somewhere in your application and register the global filter. The filter is traversing all properties and their properties, etc. and DateTime.Date is of type DateTime which causes endless recursion. Would probably happen in any hierarchy where a class is used recursively. Using the nuget package kills the app without saying where the problem is, so in the current version (6.0.0) is too dangerous and unstable to use.