# Is there a way to customize parameter name for route in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, customization

In ASP.NET controllers for example, it is possible to create a method and at the same time provide customized, exposed name for the action. So C# method could be named `GetReal`, while exposed name could be `get-real` or `whatever`. Same applies for controllers themselves, and parameters.

And I am looking exactly for the same for parameters used in routes in Blazor pages.

Let's consider

```
@page "/edit/{WordId:long?}"
...

  [Parameter]
  public long? WordId { get; set; }
```

So my C# code name is exposed to public. I would like to add my custom name -- similarly to ASP.Net I described in the beginning -- so I could write (it does not work currently):

```
@page "/edit/{my-custom-id:long?}"
...

  [Parameter(Name = "my-custom-id")]
  public long? WordId { get; set; }
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

*I already mentioned "route", not "query", but just in case, clarification -- this question is about route parameter, not query ones.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remap an MVC action parameter to another parameter name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810295/how-do-i-remap-an-mvc-action-parameter-to-another-parameter-name)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, no, this is what I described in the beginning, the controllers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change this like you changing method names in controllers.

The implementation is here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/e1ebf00fbe63aa372051ef1c184895f169ca49f5/src/Components/Components/src/Reflection/ComponentProperties.cs#L357

And there (and in used types) is nothing other then really using the param name (while being case insensitive).

But there is not the "exposing" reason as for method names and paths in controllers, because it's not translated in any uri (it is just part of the segment in your code).

`@page "/edit/{this-is-not-exposed-anywhere:long}"`

Also note you can do something like this to have different param name and "code" in the page attribute:

```
@attribute [Route(CustomRoutesParams.WordId)]

...

[Parameter] public long MyCustomId { get; set; }
```

```cs
public static class CustomRoutesParams
{
    public const string WordId = "/{MyCustomId:long}";
}
```

Another solution is to use the `nameof` which will remove the need for the magic string and in case of refactoring (renaming of the param property) it remains working.

```
@attribute [Route($"/{{{nameof(MyCustomId)}:long}}")]
```

Comment: "it's not translated in any uri (it is just part of the segment in your code)". Yes, good point. I am already using similar approach to what you showed, the problem for me it is still fragile when it comes to refactoring. This is why I prefer to have symbols in both places, this way no matter what refactor I do there would be a match. Well, it works this way for controllers, but now I am looking for a way for pages as well.

Comment: I think I understand the need - to not have the name of param specified on two places that can easily "go out of sync". In that case you can use nameof, see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, yes, this is what I am using currently, but still looking for a better way :-).

Comment: Oh, ok. Another idea I can think of is source generators. It should be feasible to squeeze the code into just  `@page "/edit/{my-custom-id:long?}"` and let the sg figure out the param...